# How do I use reference-counted keys in a Rust HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

Let's say I'm trying to implement a `StringPrefixCounter` as a `HashMap` in Rust.  The structure needs to have two operations:

- `put` a string
- `count` the number of strings with a given `&str` prefix.

My requirements are:

- Use a `HashMap` rather than something totally different like a trie.
- `put` strings are moved into the `StringPrefixCounter`.
- `put` strings are not physically cloned in memory.
- No unsafe code.  As idiomatic as possible.

After spending half a day researching a lot of stuff, I finally came up with a solution that seems to work.  Full code is below.

However, I'm still not happy because the special `Prefix` type has a ton of boilerplate that doesn't really do much beyond what `&str` already does, and wouldn't be necessary at all in other languages.  Perhaps there is another way to do this using `&str` as the map key, referencing strings in separate storage?  If so, my requirement is that `StringPrefixCounter` also owns and encapsulates this storage somehow.  Static lifetime requirement is not acceptable.

Solution using `Prefix` type is below:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let mut counter = StringPrefixCounter::with_capacity(20);
    counter.put(String::from("abc"));
    counter.put(String::from("ab"));
    assert_eq!(counter.count("ab"), 2);
    assert_eq!(counter.count("abc"), 1);
    assert_eq!(counter.count("b"), 0);
}

struct Prefix {
    data : Rc<String>,
    len: usize,
}

impl Deref for Prefix {
    type Target = str;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.data[..self.len]
    }
}

impl Borrow<str> for Prefix {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
       self.deref()
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Prefix {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.deref() == other.deref()
    }
}

impl Eq for Prefix {}

use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

impl Hash for Prefix {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.deref().hash(state);
    }
}

struct StringPrefixCounter {
    map : HashMap<Prefix, u32>,
}

impl StringPrefixCounter {
    fn with_capacity(cap : usize) -> StringPrefixCounter {
        StringPrefixCounter{ map: HashMap::with_capacity(cap)}
    }

    fn put(&mut self, s : String) {
        let n = s.len();
        let s = Rc::new(s);
        let mut i = 1;
        while i <= n {
            let pre = Prefix{data: Rc::clone(&s), len: i};
            *self.map.entry(pre).or_insert(0) += 1;
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    fn count(&self, s : &str) -> u32 {
        *self.map.get(s).unwrap_or(&0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your suggested alternative is possible given the requirement that `StringPrefixCounter` owns the storage; see [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: It's not true that `Prefix` "wouldn't be necessary at all in other languages". Specifically, most other languages will either copy the data, or have a built-in string type that amounts to the same thing as `Prefix`. C++ is an exception where you have to write `Prefix` yourself, just as in Rust. (If by "wouldn't be necessary" you mean "I wouldn't have to write it myself" then you are right.)

Comment: I think the requirement for the key type to be `&str` makes this a duplicate of [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) If you can relax that, `Prefix` is basically a smaller version of [`OwningRef<Rc<String>, str>`](https://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/struct.OwningRef.html) with an extra layer of indirection; using `owning_ref` might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried out `OwningRef<Rc<String>, str>` as you suggested and it works like a charm!  I read the Rust book but OwningRef wasn't covered.